# Problem with system of nonlinear equations

Tags: nonlinear-system

I need help for one math project.

It's about a system of non-inear equations. The system go like this:

$$
f(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
x^5+y^3*z^4+1 \\ 
x^2*y*z \\ 
z^4-1
\end{array} 
\right.
$$

The right side of the equation is 0.

a) Calculate all the zeros in the system (manually)
b) Find the Jacobian matrix, J(x). (Notice that J(x) is singular for z = 0)
c) Consider independent two starting solutions: 
1) x(0) = {-0.01, -0.01, -0.01}T 
2) x(0) = {-0.1, -0.1, -0.1}T

I have tried something but I don't know whether I am right...

---

$$
f(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
x^5+y^3*\pm1=-1 \\ 
x^2*y*\pm1=0 \\ 
z=\pm1
\end{array} 
\right.
$$

So because in the middle line there is 0 in the right side some of X and Y must be 0.
When i get for Y=0 the result is this: $$x= -1 ,   y= 0,   z= \pm1$$

And for X=0 the result is this: $$x= 0 ,   y= -1,   z= \pm1$$

I dont know where to go after this...

Please help me. Thank you!

Comment: So it seems you have completed (a).  For (b), do you know what a Jacobian matrix is?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Well i agree with Moo answer. I know how is going now. But what to do for C) ? (Is allowed to use newton method).

Comment: @Moo Can you explain me in some steps how its going for this example? Because i havent worked with this...